# Error while building Struts Application using Ant 

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, struts2

When trying to build my Struts Application, I get the following error :

```
compile:
    [javac] /media/Data/Struts 2/2012-05-02/Struts/src/Build.xml:5: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files
    [javac] MyAction.java:5: package org.apache.struts2.interceptor does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac] MyAction.java:7: package com.opensymphony.xwork2 does not exist
    [javac] import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac] MyAction.java:10: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol: class ActionSupport
    [javac] public class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac] MyAction.java:10: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol: class SessionAware
    [javac] public class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
    [javac]                                                        ^
    [javac] MyAction.java:22: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method addActionError(java.lang.String)
    [javac] location: class com.sp.action.MyAction
    [javac]         addActionError("invalid");
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] MyAction.java:47: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method addActionError(java.lang.String)
    [javac] location: class com.sp.action.MyAction
    [javac]             addActionError("User Name ,pass cannot be error");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] MyAction.java:43: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] 7 errors

BUILD FAILED
```

My package hierarchy is `src/com/sp/action/*.java` and `src/com/sp/domain/*.java`

My build file is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="strutsComple" default="compile">
    <target name="compile">
        <fileset dir="/media/Data/Works/struts-2.3.1.2/lib/" includes="*.jar"/>
        <javac srcdir="./com/sp/"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

I have already added the two required jars to my Eclipse folder.

Can someone please point me towards what I am missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Your ant build file is *too* simple. Importing the struts jars into eclipse does nothing for your ant build. You need to configure a classpath for javac in build.xml.

```
<fileset dir="/media/Data/Works/struts-2.3.1.2/lib/" includes="*.jar"/>
<javac srcdir="./com/sp/"/>
```

should become

```
<javac srcdir="./com/sp/">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="/media/Data/Works/struts-2.3.1.2/lib/" includes="*.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</javac>
```

See this answer for another example [Getting Ant <javac> to recognise a classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722774/getting-ant-javac-to-recognise-a-classpath)

See also the doc for the [javac](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) task.

Comment: dyac! I often write answers on my mobile phone. Apparently, javac auto-corrected to JavaScript (not that anyone would capitalize the 'S').

Comment: Thank you very much and I really appreciated the help you gave thanks a lot mate.. :D and even you use mobile it clear no need to bother at all friend

Comment: @JohnWatts Haha, I know all to well the powers of auto-correct.