# How should I reference each of my project's dependencies?

Tags: version-control, project-management, dependency-management

I think I want to store RoadRunner as source in my project repository. By adding a build file to the RoadRunner source code, I have created a generic build process. Does this count as modifying the project? The build file could be used by other projects to compile RoadRunner, but I don't know yet what those might be.

I think I want to store Apache Ant as binary outside my project repository. I don't think I'm going to modify Ant, I don't think I'm going to need more than one version, and I will probably use it to drive build processes in other projects.

The compile script below refers to the ant tool using the relative path `apache-ant-1.8.4\bin\ant`. I could install it in Program Files and add its `bin` directory to the path and just refer to `ant` instead.

I see Ant as an external dependency in the same way as I see Java. I've never had a compelling reason to store the exact Java distribution in my project repository.

In the interests of keeping all my dependencies in one place, I could keep a copy of the Apache Ant binaries in the repository. This is how the RoadRunner tool distributes its dependencies on NekoHTML, Xerces, and its own RoadRunner library. Taken to the extreme, I might include Java, Windows, and all my device drivers. Where is the appropriate dividing line?

#### Apache Ant

To compile the RoadRunner source, I chose Apache Ant as an automated build tool. It's easier than using command-line tricks to do [recursive compilation with javac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623161/javac-option-to-compile-recursively), and will provide more flexibility when I need it.

I don't want to modify Ant or examine its implementation, but I need it to execute a build script. In this case, the binary distribution is more convenient than the source distribution. I downloaded the version 1.8.4 [binary archive](http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/) into my own project's working directory, and unzipped the archive into a subdirectory called apache-ant-1.8.4.

#### RoadRunner

[RoadRunner](http://www.dia.uniroma3.it/db/roadRunner/index.html) is an experimental open-source tool written in Java for generating data-extraction wrappers for HTML. I want to use it in my own business intelligence project.

I want to study RoadRunner's implementation and might modify it to fit my needs. In this case, the source distibution is convenient. In any case, there is no binary distribution. I downloaded the version 0.02.11 [source archive](http://www.dia.uniroma3.it/db/roadRunner/software.html) my own project's working directory, and unzipped the archive into a subdirectory called RoadRunner.

I adapted the Apache Ant [example buildfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#example) and added it to the RoadRunner directory. It looks like this:

```
<project name="RoadRunner" default="build" basedir=".">
    <description>
        simple example build file
    </description>
  <!-- set global properties for this build -->
  <property name="src" location="src/roadrunner"/>
  <property name="build" location="build"/>
  <property name="dist"  location="dist"/>

  <path id="lib">
    <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722774/getting-ant-javac-to-recognise-a-classpath -->
    <fileset dir="lib">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>

  <target name="init">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by build -->
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="build" depends="init"
        description="build the source " >
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" classpathref="lib"/>
  </target>

  <target name="dist" depends="build"
        description="generate the distribution" >
    <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/lib"/>

    <!-- Put everything in ${build} into the MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar file -->
    <jar jarfile="${dist}/lib/MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar" basedir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="clean"
        description="clean up" >
    <!-- Delete the ${build} and ${dist} directory trees -->
    <delete dir="${build}"/>
    <delete dir="${dist}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

#### Compiling RoadRunner

Now I can compile RoadRunner from the root of my project directory using a command like this:

```
apache-ant-1.8.4\bin\ant -buildfile RoadRunner\build.xml
```

The output is a set of class files in the new `RoadRunner\build` directory.

I've saved this command into a batch script called `Compile RoadRunner.bat`.

I think I should commit at least the Ant project and the batch script into my project, but I'm unsure about the rest.

Answer (score 0):

> By adding a build file to the RoadRunner source code, I have created a generic build process. Does this count as modifying the project?

### Yes, it does

Anything that helps **reproduce the build** is part of the project history.
Anything that is generated or already built (like a third-party library) should be stored outside the source control referential (ideally, in an artifact repository like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/)), and only *declared* in a build file.

In your case, commit whatever you need in order for another developer to be able to:

- clone
- launch the build (which will find al the necessary dependencies)
- test the resulting delivery produced by said build.